# Can't understand the Schlick model formula

Tags: shaders, fragment-shader

I'm trying to implement the Schlick shading model in the fragment shader. I took the formulas from Karsten Schwenk's "a survey of shading models for real-time rendering":

[image]
[image]
[image]

1. First of all I don't understand why there's H and H'. Isn't the halfway vector unique for both layers? It says that just p,r and F vary from layer to layer. But the fragment is the same, so I don't understand how to compute H';
2. I also don't understand, for how it may seem banal, what does [F D] mean. Is that just a plain multiplication? I don't understand why it uses the bracket square syntax;
3. To compute D' should I replace p with p' and r with r' ?

Comment: The [F D] syntax might be componentwise multiplication of RGB colors.  Authors sometimes use a special syntax for that, though there is no standard for what that syntax is.  As for the other questions, you might have to track down a copy of the original Schlick paper to explain those more fully.